# What do all these numbers mean after the background?

Tags: html, css

I have seen:

```
background: url("images/tabs.gif") repeat scroll 100% 0 transparent;
background: url("images/tabs.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 #BBDDFF;
```

And I dont get what all the values after the bracket are meant to represent. Is there a doucment that will tell me?

The only stuff I could find online was referring to individual background props..

Comment: Look at the number of answers quoting W3Schools and mistaking them for the official W3C group. Just... wow.

Comment: @BoltClock XD lol I was amazed... they all came out of nowhere!

Comment: @BoltClock, it still scares me how popular that site is.

Comment: If you google "background css" it occupies the first 4 results.  It's a stink that will never go away it seems.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: It's true though, that site still comes up first in many, many search results. These days I automatically append a "site:w3.org" to my searches - takes only a second to type with muscle memory (and, *-ahem-*, good typing skills).

Comment: How could you not find this information using Google? There are *so many* resources with this information: http://www.google.com/search?q=css+background+shorthand :)

Comment: He wanted to give us a good opportunity to trash w3schools at SA.  Prescient.

Comment: @BoltClock You can block w3schools.com from your search results if you're logged in :) (See [Google's help doc](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1224171&answer=1210386&rd=1))

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: The Managed Blocked Sites page is what I've been hoping for to exist since the block link never comes up for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a breakdown of them, for your usage:**

```
//First Background

url("images/tags.gif"): background-image (the actual background image)
repeat                : background-repeat (determines if the background repeats)
scroll                : background-attachment (states if it is fixed or scrolls)
100%                  : background-position (top)
0                     : background-position (left)
transparent           : background-color
```

**likewise:**

```
//Second Background

url("images/tabs.gif") : background-image
repeat                 : background-repeat
scroll                 : background-attachment
0                      : background-position (top)
0                      : background-position (left)
#BBDDFF;               : background-color
```

**For more information or documentation, check through some of the other links found in this question. Below is a link specifically going through the background-related properties:**

[**W3 | CSS (Background-Specific)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/)

Comment: Much better breakdown, I like +1

Comment: Note, the background color should be the first property as per the W3 spec, it is implementation-dependent if you leave the color at the end.

Comment: @Bob where in the spec does it actually say that? Examples XV, XVII, & XVIII all do not have the color first, and the last example has it last.

Comment: That is wierd, CSS 2 Spec has it first: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html however, you are correct: `A double bar (||) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order.`  which means that they are order-independent.  I retract my statement

Answer (score 3):

Link to the w3c spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html

The numbers are left and top positioning.

Comment: Thank you for not posting a w3s link like all the other people! :P +1

Comment: It always gets me that backgrounds are defined in the CSS2 Colors and Backgrounds document but in the CSS3 Backgrounds and Borders module.

Answer (score 1):

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html) says the `background` shorthand CSS property is defined as:

> background: [<'background-color'> || <'background-image'> || <'background-repeat'> || <'background-attachment'> || <'background-position'>] | inherit

So you can look at the 'simple' properties and figure out the shorthand.

In you example:

```
            background-color  background-image       background-repeat background-attachment  background-position
                                                                                              X    Y
background: transparent       url("images/tabs.gif") repeat            scroll                 100% 0 ;
background: #BBDDFF           url("images/tabs.gif") repeat            scroll                 0    0 ;
```

Note that I moved the color back to the front where it is supposed to be

Comment: W3 Schools has **no** affiliation with the W3C

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background

```
[ <background-color> || <background-image> || <background-repeat> || <background-attachment> || <background-position> ]
|  inherit || <background-color>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Scroll down to "Background - Shorthand property".

Comment: lol it's so hard to avoid w3fools... It's the first 4 results on any sort of CSS googling.  You have to jump through an extra hoop to find the w3c spec.

Comment: ok, sorry, though in this case the question is so basic it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Principle, my friend. It matters in principle. :P

Comment: @M. Cypher, wrong, W3 Schools makes no mention of rgba or hsl color values, so it is incomplete.

Comment: @numbers, if you log into your google account when searching you can block the entire w3schools.com domain from appearing in search results . See this [Google help doc](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1224171&answer=1210386&rd=1).

Answer (score -1):

Its Css Shorthand

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Read "Background - Shorthand property"

Comment: @Joseph now that you mention it, i will take care next time :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

When using the shorthand property the order of the property values are:

background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position

scroll to the bottom of this page

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp